# Is it forbidden to speak between the Bracha (NOT Hamotzi) and eating?

Tags: blessing, eating

If one speaks between making a blessing on food–other than Hamotzi–must he/she repeat the blessing? By way of example, one says the *haeitz* blessing but then someone comes asking for *tzedaka* or a child needs help or the like, before the person can take a bite out of the pear. Should the blessing be repeated? Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Why might hamotzi be different?

Comment: Bc with hamotzi you could ask for something relevant to the bracha like pass the salt maybe...

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 206:3) rules that one is not allowed to make an interruption, between reciting the Bracha and eating the food. The context there is regarding “Borei Pri Ha’eitz” and “Borei Pri Ha’adamah”.

The Mishnah Berurah (ad loc. 12) differentiates between verbally speaking out, and merely delaying eating from the food.

If a person **spoke out**, even one impertinent word, then they must repeat the Bracha.

However if a person delayed eating from the food after making the Bracha, but **didn’t speak out**, then B’dieved they don’t need to repeat the Bracha, as long as they haven’t been totally distracted from the Bracha they just recited.

Nevertheless, Lechatchila, there should never be any interruption whatsoever, even if it is non-verbal.

Comment: "impertinent" given the OPs examples, it's worth defining that more precisely. Giving charity might arguably be similar to giving food to your animals which is not impertinent.

Comment: @DoubleAA What makes something be considered as לצורך הברכה?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to define it precisely, but let's look at the Mishna Berura's examples of what doesn't count as a full interruption: ואפילו הפסיק בדברים שאינו לצורך פרוסת המוציא רק מעניני צרכי סעודה ואפילו דיבר להביא הכלים שהן לצורך הסעודה לא הוי הפסק and also תנו לפלוני לאכול - בין עני ובין עשיר ואפילו לא אמר שיתנו לו מפרוסת המוציא אלא אמר לב"ב שיתנו לו ככר שיברך בעצמו מ"מ מעניני סעודה הוא

Comment: @DoubleAA All the examples cited, are related to the meal at hand; even if only tangentially, such as giving instructions to bring dishes needed for the meal. I don’t see how giving charity is related to the meal.

Comment: Perhaps peace of mind at his meal? Perhaps he is obligated to help out the needy immediately due to bal teacher / lo tikpotz et yadekha? Perhaps we have a kal vachomer from משיב מפני הכבוד in shema? I'm not so sure, and apparently neither are you.

Comment: @DoubleAA Having just recited a ברכה, his primary mandate now is, not to cause the ברכה to turn into a ברכה לבטלה. That is accomplished by first taking a bite, before responding to anyone’s queries. Not to do so, is getting involved in things that negate the ברכה.

Comment: that is literally the definition of a circular argument

Comment: @DoubleAA You are trying to expand what is considered as לצורך הברכה, without providing any authoritative sources to support such expansion. Therefore, sticking to my argument, which is rooted in OC 167:6, and which the MB referred to, is perfectly valid.

Comment: Both your statements are false. First, I am not trying to expand anything but just define a concept. Second you have no [non-circular] arguments from anywhere; just assertions.

Answer (score 0):

The Shulchan Aruch in סימן ר"ו is speaking about brachos on fruits and other foods and states in 'סעיף ג;

> כל אלו הברכו' צריך שלא יפסיק בין ברכ' לאכיל': הגה יותר מכדי דיבור [ב"י בשם שיבולי לקט]

The Mishna Berura in ס"ק יב says;

> יותר מכדי דיבור - היינו כדי שאילת תלמיד לרב שהוא שלום עליך רבי ויותר מהכי חשיב הפסק ומיירי בשתיקה אבל דיבור אפילו מלה אחת הוי הפסק כל שהוא שלא לצורך הברכה וכמבואר בסימן קס"ז ס"ו עי"ש עוד יש חילוק בין שתיקה לדיבור דבדיבור הוא לעיכובא וצריך לחזור ולברך אבל בשתיקה הוא רק לכתחלה אבל בדיעבד אפילו שהה הרבה יותר מכדי דיבור א"צ לחזור ולברך כל שלא הסיח דעתו בינתים. כתבו האחרונים דאפילו מפני הכבוד והיראה אסור להפסיק אחר הברכה ואם הפסיק חוזר ומברך ואפילו לעניית אמן או לקדיש וקדושה וברכו ג"כ לא יפסיק. לא יברך על מאכל או משקה שהוא חם או קר ביותר משום חשש הפסק. ומי שבירך על מאכל ולאחר שבירך נמאס בעיניו יש לו לאכול קצת שלא יהיה הברכה לבטלה. הרוצה לשתות מים ששופך קצת ממנו ישפוך תחלה ואח"כ יברך דתרווייהו איתנהו משום הפסק ומשום ביזוי ברכה כ"כ בשערי תשובה בסי' ר"ב בשם אחרונים. כשאוכל אגוז ישברנה ואח"כ יברך דאין כדאי להפסיק הרבה בין הברכה לאכילה ועוד שמא לא ימצאנה יפה ואינה ראויה לברכה ולענין שארי פירות עיין לעיל בסימן ר"ב בשערי תשובה:

So in your case it would be required to make a new bracha.

Comment: Why do you assume that the person would be required to make a new Bracha? The examples given in the OP, do NOT mention that the person verbally spoke out; merely, that they helped a child, or gave charity.

Comment: The OP stated "If one speaks between making..." Hence my assumption

Comment: IsraelReader, thank you so very much for your incisive and very helpful response. I am most grateful. Yes, I did mean that there was speaking between the Bracha and the eating. I was not as clear as I should have been. Many thanks again and kol tuv.